# Is there a PostgreSQL listener for changes on row table?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, amazon-aurora

i am currently using firebase firestore as a database for a web app. Now i am trying to migrate to a RDB, like AWS Aurora with PostgreSQL.
I am stuck in finding the same listener for chagnes [that Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) has. In Firestore DB i can listen for changes on single/multiple documents. In POstgreSQL, apart from LISTEN and NOTIFY commands, that would not suit our needs (Maximum of 8000 bytes in the payload), i found nothing.
Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time
Have a nice day

EDIT: For "change" i mean whenever a field (or a group of fields) of a particular record in my RDB gets updated

Comment: You don't describe what "a change on a document" means in a relational database, but perhaps you are looking for a trigger.

Comment: For "change" i mean whenever a field (or a group of fields) of a particular record in my RDB gets updated @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Right, a trigger.

Comment: Ok. I am not sure if the trigger is the correct solution as the field i wanto to observe for changes is frequently updated. The use case is a simultaneous collaboration between 2 users on a same db resource @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: And you don't want your unspecified action to happen at every change? Perhaps you should edit the question and describe your requirement in some more detail.

Comment: Sorry but i think i've been specific enough (?). What do you mean by "unspecified action"? I clearly explained that i want to observe for changes of a field of a record in a database, meaning when the record gets UPDATED i want to know it and have the new data. I want to happen at every change, of course, since i want to observe for changes @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Well, for one I don't know what a Firestore listener is. "I want to know it" sounds a bit vague to me. Anyway, the solution is and remains a trigger, and I will stop commenting.

Comment: In fact i put a link to firestore listener. I think it's a better soultion than explaining it myself in the question(?)@LaurenzAlbe

Comment: Firestore(NoSQL) != Postgres(SQL), so you will have to expect things will work differently. As @LaurenzAlbe stated the answer in Postgres is a trigger and associated function. Now in that function you can put a `NOTIFY` that includes the PK for the changed row, so you can look it up. You can also copy the data to a log table for a history.

Comment: @RettoScorretto [this post](https://ds0nt.com/postgres-streaming-listen-notify-go) has an example of how to handle large payloads via chunking if you want to go with `LISTEN`/`NOTIFY` and triggers which could work for you.

I'd also be curious to hear about your use case as I'm looking into a similar problem, what were your Firestore listeners doing that made you not want to port them to application-level logic?